# issue populating chart.js from entity framework in .Net Core 5

Tags: javascript, c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, chart.js

I am trying to populate a chart with test data before using production data but I cannot get the data into the chart. I do not have any errors that I can find and the controller is returning 2 complete datasets on the `return Json(_chart);`. The chart displays but there is no data in the chart. What am I doing wrong here?

index.cshtml

```
    <head>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           jQuery.extend({
               getValues: function (url) {
                   var result = null;
                   $.ajax({
                       url: url,
                       type: 'get',
                       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                       dataType: 'json',
                       async: false,
                       sucess: function (data) {
                           result = data;
                       }
                   });
                   return result;
               }
           });
       </script>  
    </head>
    
    <body>
       <canvas id="myLineChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>

       <script type="text/javascript">
           var ctx = document.getElementById("myLineChart").getContext('2d');
           var tData = $.getValues("/Home/MultiLineChartDataEF");
           var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
               type: 'line',
               data: tData
           });
       </script>
    </body>
```

HomeController.cs

```
        public JsonResult MultiLineChartDataEF()
        {
            var chartData = _context.ChartTests.ToList();
            var uniqueProducts = from d in chartData orderby d.ProductName group d by d.ProductName into m select m.Key;
            var uniqueMonths = from a in chartData orderby a.MonthNumber group a by a.Month into g select g.Key;
            string[] cols = new string[] { "#FF0000", "#000000" };
            int i = 0;
            Chart _chart = new();
            _chart.labels = uniqueMonths.ToArray();
            _chart.datasets = new List<Datasets>();
            List<Datasets> _dataSet = new();
            foreach(var d in uniqueProducts)
            {
                var colors = new string[uniqueProducts.Count()];
                for (int j = 0; j < colors.Length; j++) colors[j] = cols[i];
                _dataSet.Add(new Datasets()
                {
                    label = d,
                    data = (from a in chartData where a.ProductName == d select a.Amount).ToArray(),
                    backgroundColor = new string[] { cols[i] },
                    borderColor = new string[] { cols[i] },
                    borderWidth = "1"
                });
                i++;
            }
            _chart.datasets = _dataSet;
            return Json(_chart);
        }
```

Chart.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ChartTest.Models
{
    public class Chart
    {
        public string[] labels { get; set; }
        public List<Datasets> datasets { get; set; }
    }
    public class Datasets
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string[] backgroundColor { get; set; }
        public string[] borderColor { get; set; }
        public string borderWidth { get; set; }
        public string[] data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ChartTest.cs

```
namespace ChartTest.Models
{
    public partial class ChartTest
    {
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string Month { get; set; }
        public string Amount { get; set; }
        public int? MonthNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot of the empty chart]

Comment: You cannot use getValues() the way you are using it.  Ajax call takes some time, but result is being returned immediately.  Add console.log('returning result'); just before the return line, and add another console.log('ajax success'); inside of the ajax success callback.  You will see 'returning result' happens before 'ajax success'.

Comment: @hijinxbassist Can I resolve this by using an async function in Javascript along with fetch?

Comment: Personally, I would just populate the chart (or call a populate method) from inside of the success function.  Since you want to reuse that function, perhaps add a callback function parameter that you call on success with the results

Comment: I just realized that your ajax is marked as async=false.  That forces the wait you expect, but can cause huge problems.  Are you sure your ajax call is producing results?  Have you checked in the browser console?

Comment: @hijinxbassist something is wrong with the call. It is returning false (error) instead of success for some reason. I'm trying to troubleshoot it but I can't seem to find a way to display the error to either an alert or console.log. It's just showing null

Comment: Try running the project locally with the project in debug mode.  Put a break line on all of the lines and step through each one.  Eventually it will break out of the controller context, whichever line it stopped at is where the error occurred.  You could also wrap the entire code in a Try/Catch block, and examine the exception.

Comment: If the controller is not causing the error, then I suspect it is the url you are using.  Try changing the url from `/Home/MultiLineChartDataEF` to `@Url.Action("MultiLineChartDataEF", "Home")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a spelling mistake of your ajax, the success of the Ajax call should be "success", not "sucess", after I corrected it, the data can be fetched normally.

```
jQuery.extend({
           getValues: function (url) {
               var result = null;
               debugger;
               $.ajax({
                   url: url,
                   type: 'get',
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   dataType: 'json',
                   async: false,
                   success: function (data) {
                       result=data;
                   },
                   error:function(){
                       return error;
                   }
               });
               return result;
           }
       });
```

**Test Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! jQuery and Javascript never threw an error but it works great now! It just took that 2nd set of eyes.